# Check if a tweet has already been retweeted - Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

so I am trying to make a bot and I am trying to see if a tweet has been retweeted before I try and retweet. The issue is I cannot seem to find a way to do it. I have tried many ways as seen below but I cannot figure it out. I have checked Stackoverflow and Twitter4j but cannot find a solution

My code:

```
private boolean retweetedAlready(Status status) throws TwitterException {
    System.out.println("Status ID: " + status.getId());
    System.out.println("Retweeted: " + status.isRetweetedByMe());

    List<Status> retweets = twitter.getRetweetsOfMe();
    Status tmp;
    for(Status s : twitter.getUserTimeline()){
        tmp = s.getRetweetedStatus();
        System.out.println("ID: " + s.getId());
        System.out.println("Equal: " + status.equals(s));
        System.out.println("Retweeted Status id: " + tmp.getId());
        System.out.println(tmp.getId() + ", " + status.getId() + " - " + (tmp.getId() == status.getId()));
        System.out.println(retweets.contains(status));
        System.out.println();
        if(s.getRetweetedStatus().getId() == status.getId()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The output:

```
Status ID: 712688409878331392
Retweeted: false
ID: 712688575494688768
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712654036646891520
712654036646891520, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712688572063752194
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712687766178365441
712687766178365441, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712688568678875137
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712663978158071810
712663978158071810, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712364624251846658
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712226571634008065
712226571634008065, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712364621743661060
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712056778410713088
712056778410713088, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361537680310274
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712345290464886784
712345290464886784, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361535302180864
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712361382474346497
712361382474346497, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361075149246466
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712360810211897344
712360810211897344, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361072687239168
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712360816801136641
712360816801136641, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361069872877569
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712310621748862978
712310621748862978, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361066936799232
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712360862120435712
712360862120435712, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712361063744929792
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712360922182975490
712360922182975490, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712360695069872130
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712360559329595392
712360559329595392, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712360607538946050
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712349483066105856
712349483066105856, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712359955043635201
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712292676352274433
712292676352274433, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712359949565870080
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712359728286965765
712359728286965765, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712359946835333120
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712359289365499904
712359289365499904, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712359944209764352
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 709161338342248448
709161338342248448, 712688409878331392 - false
false

ID: 712359940627816448
Equal: false
Retweeted Status id: 712359805805993985
712359805805993985, 712688409878331392 - false
false
```

Comment: You don't show the Status class, but I suspect you'll have to keep track of your tweets yourself in a database to see if you previously tweeted a tweet.

Comment: Status is a Twitter4j class. And I can get the tweets but I can't seem to find if it's the same one. I don't want to just check text because someone could do the same as another. The id is different and I can't check if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think use `status.getRetweetCount()` this return total retweet number is tweet, if is equal is zero is not retweeted but is greater than zero is retweeted

and check yourself retweeted is `status.isRetweetedByMe()`

```
   private boolean retweetedAlready(Status status) throws TwitterException {

        if(status.isRetweetedByMe() && status.getRetweetCount() > 1 ){

        return true; // this twit retweeted by your and others
    } else if(status.isRetweetedByMe() && status.getRetweetCount() == 1 )
        return  true; // this twit only retweeted by your
    }else{
        return false; // this twit not retweeted by your but mybe others retweeted
    }
```

}

and change `getUserTimeline()` with `getHomeTimeline()` for fetch tweets,`isRetweetedByMe()` not works with `getUserTimeline()`

Comment: Tried, you can see in my example above as well I check that and it always returns false in this case.

Comment: Again, this wont help. isRetweetedByMe always returns false. I can't just check the count because even if 1 it could not be me.

Comment: isRetweetedByMe() always returns "false" why this api fuction please debug your code

Comment: I am test now.  isRetweetedByMe() return true for me bulid your project try after

Comment: I'm doing a query and going through them tweets, isRetweetedByMe doesn't work there, only on the timeline.

Comment: yes isRetweetedByMe() works only with timeline methods. api creator Yusuke say here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter4j/xt9UxC-xYnc

Comment: and change getUserTimeline() with getHomeTimeline() try after it works

Comment: @bwfcwalshy  I edited my answer isRetweetedByMe() not works with  getUserTimeline()